# Blazor wasm Web API response is an HTML string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

Ok i have a wasm App that call the server side web api endpoints.
The problem is that I get the index.html page from the /wwwroot directory for an endpoint as an answer. But when I address the endpoint with Postman I get the json answer as expected.
Okay i will show how i do this with my code.

## Client Side data flow

### Search.razor Page

Here I call the Web API endpoint when a search text has been entered in the form field. That works as expected.

```
... Snip

// UPDATED INFO
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="objectType">Select object type</label>
    <select id="objectType" class="form-control" @bind="@_searchByNameObjectTypeUuid">
        @if (_objectTypes != null)
        {
            @foreach (var objectType in _objectTypes)
            {
                @if (objectType.TypeName == "Music")
                {
                    @* This selection value is not set. But why?
                    <option value="@objectType.Uuid.ToString("D")" selected="selected">@objectType.TypeName</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@objectType.Uuid.ToString("D")">@objectType.TypeName</option>
                }
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
// UPDATED INFO END

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="objectName">Object name:<br/></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="objectName" @onkeydown="@SearchByNameOnEnter" @bind-value="@_searchByNameObjectNamePhrase" @bind-value:event="oninput"/>
</div>

...Snip

@code {
    private string _searchByNameObjectNamePhrase = string.Empty;

    private async Task SearchByNameOnEnter(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter") && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_searchByNameObjectNamePhrase))
        {
            _searchResult = await ServerApiClient.SearchObjectsByNamePhrase(_searchByNameObjectTypeUuid, _searchByNameObjectNamePhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

### ServerApiClientService.cs Web API Client service

With this I call different Web API endpoints that get the data from a database in the backend.

The `GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount()` method works as expected.

The method `SearchObjectsByNamePhrase(string objTypeUuid, string searchTermPhrase)` sends me the file /wwwroot/index.html as an answer. (Show comments in code for details)

```
namespace WebAssembly.Client.Services
{
    public class ServerApiClientService : IServerApiClientService
    {
        #region Constants - Static fields - Fields
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        #endregion
        
        #region Constructors and Destructors
        public ServerApiClientService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        #endregion
        
        #region Methods
        // This endpoint request work as expected
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ObjectAttributeValueCount>> GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount()
        {
            IEnumerable<ObjectAttributeValueCount> result =
                await _httpClient
                    .GetFromJsonAsync<List<ObjectAttributeValueCount>>("/api/DdsDashboard/GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount");
            return (result ?? Array.Empty<ObjectAttributeValueCount>()).AsQueryable();
        }

        // This endpoint request NOT work as expected
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResultItem>> SearchObjectsByNamePhrase(string objTypeUuid, string searchTermPhrase)
        {
            // For test i have called as string and i get HTML response. wwwroot/index.html is comming back.
            var asJsonString =
                await _httpClient
                        .GetStringAsync($"/api/DdsDashboard/SearchObjectsByNamePhrase/{objTypeUuid}/{searchTermPhrase}");

            // And here i get the exception "System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException"
            // '<' is an invalid start of a value
            IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> result =
                await _httpClient
                    .GetFromJsonAsync<List<SearchResultItem>>($"/api/DdsDashboard/SearchObjectsByNamePhrase/{objTypeUuid}/{searchTermPhrase}");

            return (result ?? Array.Empty<SearchResultItem>()).AsQueryable();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

## Server Side data flow

### DdsDashboardController.cs as the Web API Controller

All methods (routes) in this controller work perfectly when I address them with Postman.

The route `[HttpGet("GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount")]` and the route `[HttpGet("GetDdsObjectTypeStatistic")]` also work with the ServerApiClientService.cs.

Only the route [HttpGet ("SearchObjectsByNamePhrase / {objTypeId} / {searchTerm}")] only works in Postman.

```
namespace WebAssembly.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DdsDashboardController : ControllerBase
    {
    #region Constants - Static fields - Fields

        private readonly IDdsRepository _repository;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Destructors

        public DdsDashboardController(IDdsRepository repo)
        {
            _repository = repo;
        }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

        [HttpGet("GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ObjectAttributeValueCount>> GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount()
        {
            return await _repository.GetDdsObjectAttributeValueCount();
        }

        [HttpGet("GetDdsObjectTypeStatistic")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ObjectTypeStatistic>> GetDdsObjectTypeStatistic()
        {
            return await _repository.GetDdsObjectTypeStatistic();
        }

        // This method is called and worked as expected. When i call this endpoint with Postman all is fine. Correct JSON response.
        [HttpGet("SearchObjectsByNamePhrase/{objTypeId}/{searchTerm}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResultItem>> SearchObjectsByNamePhrase(string objTypeId, string searchTerm)
        {
            // Correct result from my database. I have checked with an breakpoint.
            var result = await _repository.SearchObjectsByNamePhrase(objTypeId, searchTerm);

            return result;
        }

    #endregion
    }
}
```

## Startup.cs

### Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{

    if (Env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }

    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                     {
                         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                         endpoints.MapControllers();
                         endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
                     });
}
```

### ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new MySqlGuidTypeHandler());
    SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(Guid));
    SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(Guid?));

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddScoped<IDdsRepository, DdsRepository>();

    var dbConnectionSettings = new DdsDbConnectionConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("DdsDbSettings"));
    services.AddSingleton(dbConnectionSettings);

    if (!Env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
                                     {
                                         options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
                                         options.HttpsPort          = 443;
                                     });
    }
}
```

## Request with Postman

[image: Postman Result]

I hope I have given enough information to be able to give me an indication of why this not work.

## Update

Ok. The problem is that the binding for the  form control worked only when i make manualy a selection change. Set a selected  while rendering is not working.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="objectType">Select object type</label>
    <select id="objectType" class="form-control" @bind="@_searchByNameObjectTypeUuid">
        @if (_objectTypes != null)
        {
            @foreach (var objectType in _objectTypes)
            {
                @if (objectType.TypeName == "Music")
                {
                    <option value="@objectType.Uuid.ToString("D")" selected="selected">@objectType.TypeName</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@objectType.Uuid.ToString("D")">@objectType.TypeName</option>
                }
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

And that's why the `_searchByNameObjectTypeUuid` value is not set.
And with that `endpoints.MapFallbackToFile(" index.html ")`.

I have set the value of `_searchByNameObjectTypeUuid` in the `OnInitializedAsync()` method where also i load the `_objectTypes`.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _objectTypes = await DdsApiClient.GetObjectTypes();
    _searchByNameObjectTypeUuid = _objectTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeName == "Music")?.Uuid.ToString("D");
}
```

If anyone knows how to set the value with the foreach loop while rendering, I would be grateful to hear about it.

Thanks to @Neil W for help.

Comment: Try getting the result in your clientAPI into an HttpResponseMessage first.  Then inspect that.  What status code are you getting back? >>>> HttpResponseMessage res = await _httpClient                      .GetAsync($"/api/DdsDashboard/SearchObjectsByNamePhrase/{objTypeUuid}/{searchTermPhrase}"); >>> That may give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks Neil W. That have realy give a hint. The ```{objTypeUuid}``` was not set initial. I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer for your question directly, but when I first started encountering challenges with WebAPI from Blazor wasm client, I create a client API base class, thus:

```
public abstract class ClientAPI
{
    protected readonly HttpClient Http;
    private readonly string BaseRoute;

    protected ClientAPI(string baseRoute, HttpClient http)
    {
        BaseRoute = baseRoute;
        Http = http;
    }

    protected async Task<TReturn> GetAsync<TReturn>(string relativeUri)
        => await ProcessHttpResponse<TReturn>(await Http.GetAsync($"{BaseRoute}/{relativeUri}"));

    protected async Task<TReturn> PostAsync<TReturn, TRequest>(string relativeUri, TRequest request)
        => await ProcessHttpResponse<TReturn>(await Http.PostAsJsonAsync($"{BaseRoute}/{relativeUri}", request));

    private static async Task<TReturn> ProcessHttpResponse<TReturn>(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TReturn>();

        string msg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
}
```

Then my derived Client API class would call GetAsync on the base class.  That will then either resolve the Json response or if the HttpResponseMessage had a failure status code, it would log the error.

Use from derived class like this:

```
public class BackOfficeClientAPI : ClientAPI
{
    public BackOfficeClientAPI(HttpClient http) : base("api/backoffice", http) { }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> GetCategoriesAsync(Guid organisationId)
        => await GetAsync<IEnumerable<Category>>($"getcategories?organisationId={organisationId}");

    public async Task<Category> AddCategoryAsync(AddCategoryRequest request)
        => await PostAsync<Category, AddCategoryRequest>("addcategory", request);
```

PS.  I'm using querystring instead of route parameters, but the principle is the same.

I've found it a nice pattern to catch exceptions of this type.

Comment: Thanks for this pattern. It's a good idea.